# awk does not get multiple matches in a line with match

Tags: awk

AWK has the match(s, r [, a]) function which according to the manual is capable of recording all occuring patterns into array "a":

...If array a is provided, a is cleared and then elements 1 through n are filled with the portions of s that match the corresponding parenthesized subexpression in r. The 0'th element of a contains the portion of s matched by the entire regular expression r. Subscripts a[n, "start"], and a[n, "length"] provide the starting index in the string and length respectively, of EACH matching substring.

I expect that the following line:

`echo 123412341234 | awk '{match($0,"1",arr); print arr[0] arr[1] arr[2];)`'

prints 111

But in fact "match" ignores all other matches except the first one.

Could please someone tell me please what is the proper syntax here to populate "arr" with all occurrences of "1"?

Comment: the ability for (GNU) `awk` to store multiple matches in an array is based on the regex defining multiple patterns to match (ie, items inside of parens); see [GNU awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#match) and the section for the `match()` function; in particular pay attention to the 2nd half of the discussion where the sample has 2 parenthesized patterns in the single regex: `gawk '{ match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/, arr)` which in turn is going to populate the `arr[]` array with matches for `f0+` and `bar*`

Comment: to find multiple matches in a row, using `match()`, you either have to account for them in the regex (eg, 3x paranthesized patterns in the regex to match for 3x copies of the string) or write a loop that performs a `match()` on successive chunks of the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` [`patsplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function for that task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
123412341234
```

then

```
awk '{patsplit($0,arr,"1");print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
111
```

Explanation: `patsplit` is function which allows you to get similar effect to using `FPAT` variable, it does put all matches of 3rd argument into array provided as 2nd argument (clearing it if is not empty) found in string provided as 1st argument. Observe that 1st finding does goes under key `1`, 2nd under `2`, 3rd under `3` and so on (there is nothing under `0`)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 5):

`match` only finds first match and stops there. You will have to run `match` in a loop or else use this way where we use split input on anything this is not `1`:

```
echo '123412341234' | awk -F '[^1]+' '{print $1 $2 $3}'

111
```

Or using `split` in gnu-awk:

```bash
echo '123412341234' | awk 'split($0, a, /1/, m) {print m[1] m[2] m[3]}'

111
```

Comment: then it looks like the manual is misleading. Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Manual is not totally wrong because it talks all about the context of the match. When your regex is just `/1/` that is all you will get.

Comment: what is /1/? Is there a way to expand it?

Comment: That is 2nd argument to `match` function. You used `"1"` which is same as `/1/`. There is no `matchAll` or `findall` equivalent in awk

Comment: So obviously `match` is not the right function if you to grab all the matches quickly. `split` can surely do that even `patsplit` would also do.

Comment: split does not seem to be appropriate, it uses regexp to describe separator, while patsplit uses regexp to describe the substring.

Comment: oh I see, separators are stored and you printed them, nice!

Answer (score 2):

If `sub` is allowed then you can do a substitution here. Try following `awk` code once.

```
awk '{gsub(/[^1]+/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`patsplit()` is basically same as wrapping the desired `regex` pattern with a custom pair of `SEPs` before splitting, which is what `anysplit()` is emulating here, while being `UTF-8` friendly.

```
 echo "123\uC350abc:\uF8FF:|\U1F921#xyz" | 

mawk2x '{ print ("\t\f"($0)"\n")>>(STDERR)
    
          anysplit($_, reFLEX_UCode8 "|[[-_!-/3-?]",___=2,__)
          OFS="\t"

          for(_ in __) { if (!(_%___)) { 

              printf(" matched_items[ %2d ] = # %-2d = \42%s\42\n",
                                                     _,_/___,__[_]) 
           
          } } } END { printf(ORS) }'
    
        123썐abc::|#xyz

 matched_items[  2 ] = # 1  = "3썐"
 matched_items[  4 ] = # 2  = "::"
 matched_items[  6 ] = # 3  = "#"
```

In the background, `anysplit()` is nothing all that complicated either :

> `xs3pFS` is a 3-byte string of `\301\032\365` that I assumed would be extremely rare to show up even in binary data.

```
gsub(patRE, xs3pFS ((pat=="&")?"\\":"") "&" xs3pFS,_)

gsub(xs3pFS "("xs3pFS")+", "",_)

return split(_, ar8, xs3pFS)
```

By splitting the input string in this manner, all the desired items would exist in even-numbered array indices, while the rest of the string would be distributed along odd-numbered indices,

somewhat similar to the `2nd array i.e. 4th argument` in `gawk`'s `split()` and `patsplit()` for the seps, but difference being that both the matches and the seps, whichever way you want to see them, are in the same array.

When you print out every cell in the array, you'll see :

```
        _SEPS_[  1 ] = # 1  = "123"
 matched_items
              [  2 ] = # 1  = "썐"

        _SEPS_[  3 ] = # 2  = "abc"
 matched_items
              [  4 ] = # 2  = "::"

        _SEPS_[  5 ] = # 3  = "|"
 matched_items
              [  6 ] = # 3  = "#"

        _SEPS_[  7 ] = # 4  = "xyz"
```